# how to export a variable form __init__ and use in other functions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a program that takes a Flipkart Product Link and outputs its result using different methods.Here is my code:

```
def __init__(self, link):
        res = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
```

we simply want to extract this soup variable so that other functions can access that variable, so that each time we request for any method like price, Title, we do not need to request the page again and again and slow down the Program.

For the answer provided it yielded blank but actually it should return ₹....

```
def __init__(self, link):
        res = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        self.soup = soup
def prices(self):
        prices = self.soup.find_all(text=re.compile('₹'))
        print(prices[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save it as an attribute and then you can use it in other methods

```
def __init__(self, link):
        res = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        self.soup = soup

def foo(self, arg1):
     return self.soup.blah(arg1)
```

A end to end use case would be

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
class Foo:
    
    def __init__(self, link):
        res = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html')
        self.soup = soup
    def prices(self):
        prices = self.soup.find_all(text=re.compile('td'))
        print(prices[0])

huh = Foo('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/chealjo01.html')

huh.prices()
```

NOTE: i changed a few things (parser from lxml -> html, character -> td) to get a functional example since i dont have access to same data as OP.

Comment: No bro This Doesn't Work

Comment: Note that these function will need to be inside a class, What is the issue you are facing from the above code?

Comment: Are these function within a class? could you update the question with the rest of the code?

Comment: not sure what desired output is. if you can clarify your question i can try to make my answer more specific. right now your questions is fairly vague so i had to be vague in my answer